# .htaccess rewriteCond that ignores your own domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If I have a rule in `.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^URL\=(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php? [R=404,L]
```

how would I change it so that ignores anything after `?URL=` from the site's own domain?

For example, `my-domain.com?URL=http://porn.site` gets redirected, but `my-domain.com?URL=https://my-domain.com/some-page` is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^URL\=https?://my-domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^URL\=(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php? [R=404,L]
```

Comment: So I've found that this is only working without a subdomain, i.e. `my-domain.com?URL=…` works, but `www.my-domain.com?URL=…` doesn't. I wouldn't have thought it would matter as the condition is only checking the query string.

Comment: I changed my answer for www.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. It's not whether the domain in the querystring after `?URL=` has a www or not, it's whether the domain itself has a www. So `my-domain.com?URL=my.domain.com` shows the intended page and `my-domain.com?URL=another.com` redirects to a 404 page, but `www.my-domain.com?URL=another.com` shows the intended page rather than a 404.

Comment: These rules are not linked to the domain name. So your problem is elsewhere...